# multiple values of a categorical variable , GLM , model.matrix

Tags: r, glm, model.matrix

I have a data that looks like this

```
    id var1 var2 var3 response var4
1   1    0 cat1    E        1   T4
2   1    0 cat1    E        1   T2
3   2    0 cat2    B        1 <NA>
4   3    0 cat3    C        0 <NA>
5   4    0 cat4    D        0   T3
6   4    0 cat4    D        0   T1
7   5    1 cat1    A        1   T4
8   5    1 cat1    A        1   T3
9   6    1 cat3    C        1   T3
10  7    0 cat1    C        0   T1
```

I want to run a glm for the dependent variable `"response"`

as you can see the ID's are not unique, that's because each ID can take more than one value for "var4" ,

to that end I tried `model.matrix` but it doesn't preserve the Id's, making it difficult to check the results, 
I am sure there is a simple way to do this, can someone help?

to generate the above data you can use

```
# GENERATING THE FIRST DATA FRAME

set.seed(1984)

df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                  var1 = sample(0:1, 15, replace = T, prob = c(.7,.3)), 
                  var2 = sample(c('cat1','cat2', 'cat3','cat4'),15, replace = T), 
                  var3 = sample(LETTERS[1:5],15, replace = T ), 
                  response = sample(0:1, 15, replace = T)
                  )

# GENERATING THE 2ND DATA FRAME
set.seed(1984)

df2 <- data.frame(id = sample(1:15, 20, replace = T), 
                  var4 = sample(c('T1','T2','T3','T4'), 20, replace = T))

df2 <- unique(df2[order(df2$id), ])
row.names(df2) <- NULL

# MERGING THE TWO
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'id', all = T )

df3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reshape the data using dcast from the reshape2 package.  This will reshape your data so each id is on one row and one-hot-encode var4 prior to feeding the dataframe into model.matix.  Using your minimum working example this would be something like:

```
library(reashpe2)

newDF <- dcast(df3, ...~var4,function(x) length(x))
model.matrix(response ~., newDF)
```

Comment: the solution works, thanx!, is there a way to generalize the method to all the categorical variables in the data frame (turn all the values to dummy vars) ?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand... as long as each ID is unique, model.matrix will one-hot-encode any remaining categorical variables. If you have other variables that are like var4, one maybe able to adjust the formula in dcast to get what you want.  But how exactly you go about this would depend on your data.

Comment: model.matrix is behaving strangely (eliminating some variables that were introduced by dcast), is there a way using reshape2 to get a data frame with all the values of categorical variables turned into dummy variables?

Comment: This issue is data specific so it is hard to say what is going on... I would recommend figuring out why model matrix is behaving strangely rather than just using dcast.  You will need to convert you data to a model matrix either way before running glm.

Comment: It actually doesn't, Rstudio truncates the view, thanx again.